# standard Java naming conventions?

Tags: java

i was asking a question before of a completely different topic and got to know that i am not writing code that respects java standard naming convention. first i thought it doesn't quite matter what i name my variables or methods or classes, but after reading some comments i have come to know that it indeed does.

so, will you guys please tell me what the standard java naming conventions are? and i'd probably need a good article or tutorial on it too.

also, have you had any past experience of facing problems because you don't use standard java naming conventions?

also, how much time will it take me to keep those in mind?

how do you tell weather someone is respecting the standard java naming convention?

how important is it to maintain code?

there are a bunch of other questions too but i'll save that for later.

Comment: How about googling stuff like this? "java naming conventions" leads directly to the document in ipavlic's answer!

Comment: I think these questions are not suitable in this community. May be on programmers.stackexchange. Check the following link http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/154323/environment-naming-standards-in-software-development

Comment: References to links & books were made in the earlier post to which this user is referring.  As much as I'm willing to help, I'd like to see some self-help first.  This, to me, is just asking others/same folks to repeat earlier kindly efforts.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A very short explanation:

- Class names: `MyClass` (every new word starts with a capital letter)
- Function names: `void myFunction()` (starts with a small, every new
  word with capital)
- Data members: `int myVariable` (same as function)
- Static/final members: `static final int MY_STATIC_STUFF` (all
  characters are capitals)

There is a big question with braces. Someone likes to use it like this:

```
if() {
..
}
```

and someone likes to use it like this:

```
if()
{
..
}
```

I think it's really important to follow some convention, because long codes can quickly become unreadable, if you don't. Thankfully IDEs like `NetBeans` and `Eclipse` help developers to make it easier.

Answer (score 3):

Your ultimate source of Java naming conventions should be the [Java Language Specification, Chapter 6, Section 1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.1).

Answer (score 2):

See for example http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/codeconvtoc-136057.html

Answer (score 0):

The standard naming conventions should only be thought of when sharing your code, developing with others... You don't have to keep it in mind that much as long as you feel that it is organized. Here's a link on how to do it right in case you want to show someone your code: http://java.about.com/od/javasyntax/a/nameconventions.htm

Comment: To the contrary, in Java the naming conventions are an important aspect of basic program correctness, due to the way the syntax is designed. Without respecting the naming conventions there are many opportunities for name clashes that produce confusing compiler errors in the mild case and surprising and difficult-to-understand behavior at runtime. Following Java Naming Conventions is simply a part of basic language mastery. If this weren't so, the conventions would not have been an integral part of the Java Language Specification.

Comment: What is specified in Java is the fact that naming anything with capitals or small letters will not affect the performance of the compiler.

Comment: No, John, that is by far not the **only** thing specified by the Java Language Specification. For example, there is clear potential for naming clashes when not respecting the naming convention for packages and class names.

Answer (score 0):

These are common naming conventions in java

Package Names: mypackage
Class names: NewClass
Interface names: NewInterface
Function names: void myFunction() 
instance members: int myVariable 
Static/final members: static final int  MAX_HEIGHT