# How would you write a constructor that checks that the array passed is the same length as the instance variable in the class?

Tags: java, eclipse

I need to create a class that initializes the instance variable in it. In the if statement I am getting a Type mismatch error: cannot convert from int to boolean.

```
public class ProccessForm {

    private String UserInfo[];

    public ProccessForm(String[] UserInfo) {
        UserInfo = new String[6];

        if(UserInfo.length){


        }
    }
```

Comment: Please post a particular question. In this case, almost literally all you have to do is described in the task. When you will encounter some concrete problem, post it as a reproducible example.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Int cannot be converted to boolean?? converting code from C to Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28992471/int-cannot-be-converted-to-boolean-converting-code-from-c-to-java)

Answer (score 1):

```
// if length of array passed does not equal length of current array    
if (UserInfo.length != this.length) { 

    // do this

}
```

Right now in your if statement `UserInfo.length` returns an integer, if statements deal with `Boolean` logic so you need to use a conditional operator such as `(<, >, <=, >=, ==, or !=)` when working with primitives.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a *type mismatch error* because you're trying to compare an `int` value to a `boolean` value. The `length` field of primitive arrays returns an `int` data type and `if` blocks evaluate `boolean` value so you need to compare it with another object of the same raw type. Learn more about [if-then and if-then-else statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/if.html) as well as [Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html).

The following code should show you how your code should look like but there are a couple of more issues with your code that need to be addressed.

```
public class ProcessForm {

    private String[] userInfo = new String[6];

    public ProcessForm(String[] userInfo) {

        if (this.userInfo.length == userInfo.length) {

            // Do something here...
        }
    }
}
```

- You should stick to a [standard Java naming convention](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11699804/5759072).
- You also had a typo in the class name; process is spelled with a single *c*.
- Java does not use *C-style* array declarations so you should declare your variable like this: `String[] userInfo` instead of `String userInfo[]` like you would in C language.
- There is no need to initialize the class field inside a constructor when you're not using any parameter values in the initialization process. You can just declare and initialize it on the same line.
- Remember to always use `this` keyword when you want to address class fields that have the same names as local variables otherwise you will be addressing local variables instead.